# play an infinite counter to an animiation in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

What's it's the option to add iterations, or something similar to ccs3 animation-iteration-count to angular 2 animations? I can't find anything related. How we apply an infinite play to the animation?

Where do we add that option?

```
                  animations: [
                  trigger('flyInOut', [
                    state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
                    transition('void => *', [
                      animate(1500, keyframes([
                        style({transform: 'translateX(-102%)'}),
                        style({transform: 'translateX(102%)'})
                      ]))
                    ]),
                    transition('* => void', [
                      animate(1500, keyframes([
                        style({transform: 'translateX(-102%)'}),
                        style({transform: 'translateX(102%)'})
                      ]))
                    ])
                  ])
                ]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear way in **Angular2** to do it. I mean we don't have any specific **`flag,method`** or something which we can use. I guess, it is possible to do it through **typescript code** only as shown below in your component.

```
this.state="flyIn";

constructor(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
        this.state=this.state=="flyIn"?"flyInOut":"flyIn"; 
                               //trying to change the state
  },700)                       //700 almost half of 1500
}
```

HTML

```
[@MyAnimation]="state";
```

**OR**

You can use [requestAnimationFrame](https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/). But not sure about this as **`1500ms`** timing is involved in your example.

```
repeatAnimation() {
  this.state=this.state=="flyIn"?"flyInOut":"flyIn"; 
  requestAnimationFrame(repeatAnimation);
}

constructor(){
  this.requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften);
}
```